# How to deploy Python, Flask Application on Blogger?

Tags: python, flask, deployment, blogger

I have a Flask web application, I want to deploy that in my blog/domain. How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is pretty broad question! Not too familiar with blogger but if it is a hosting service is might not allow you? Typically I would using something like Heroku and point the web domain to that application.